# MS Graph API Authentication | MS Teams | Bot framework

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, botframework, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams

I am new to bot development. I am working on creating a MS Teams bot using bot framework. The bot will be installed in ‘Personal’ scope in Teams, and it doesn’t have any tab / messaging extension etc. Once installed, I want to get the list of all the members/ channels/ Notification updates (i.e. members added/deleted etc.). As per the different documentation, I can get the list using Graph API.

1. [List members of team - Microsoft Graph v1.0 | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/team-list-members?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http)
2. [List members of a channel - Microsoft Graph v1.0 | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/channel-list-members?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http)

To achieve this, I need the token that will be passed in API. I am not sure how to implement that. I have followed the instructions mentioned in [Add authentication to a bot in Bot Framework SDK - Bot Service | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-authentication?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=userassigned%2Caadv2%2Ccsharp). There was a step to add ‘Add OAuth Connection Settings’ and there were multiple options in ‘Service Provider’. I selected ‘Azure Active Directory v2’. After doing that, it works and I can get the token, but it only works if during login, I user my azure directory credentials. I have a Microsoft account linked with my MS Teams which id different than the Azure account. A user in team can have a Microsoft account / work / office account so this needs to work for everyone so what would be the correct ‘Service Provider’ option that will work for all accounts?

I was thinking that the flow should be like:

1. When clicks on ‘Add’ button to install the app in Teams
2. Once added, bot will prompt for Graph API permission using OAuth.
3. Once user gives the permission, I can use the token to call graph APIs.

I have also looked at the following tutorials:

1. [How to use Bot Framework Composer to build low-code Microsoft Teams bots (Part 1)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ovPr1XCS9wc)
2. [Get user profile information in your Microsoft Teams bot with Microsoft Graph (Part 2) - YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Kt2I7B96aa4)

But after performing all the steps, when I try to login, it says – ‘This action can't be performed since the app does not exist or has been uninstalled.’.

I am not getting a clear approach on how to proceed with it.

Comment: Did you see this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/learn/modules/msteams-sso ?
When you develop your bot via Bot Framework Composer, you must use Bot Framework Emulator and Ngrok to test authentication. So, if it works fine during tests, after you publish bot to Azure, you must carefully setup connections in bot: one to ms graph, another to some api's. Last step - is develop MS Teams application with SSO to allow MS Teams to call authentication to this connections.

Comment: Thanks for proving that link.  It seems it's more about implementing SSO with tabs. In my case, there is no tab. The user will be installing the bot in personal scope only and then they will interact with the bot. Also, all the users are in Azure AD and hence it is working.  What about if an organization is using Microsoft Account or Gmail etc.?

Comment: As I mentioned that my Teams account is linked to Microsoft Account and Azure Account is link to different account where I setup the bot and app registration. When I install the bot and try to authenticate it using my teams account, it gives error saying - "AADSTS50020: User account test@test.com from identity provider live.com does not exist in tenant Sample and cannot access the application 5se6c0-2b1f-4285-8d4b-757346 in that tenant. The account needs to be added as an external user in the tenant first. Sign out and sign in again with a different Azure Active Directory user account."

Comment: Every bot is Azure Active Directory resource. Did your user test@test.com belongs own Azure Dicrectory? If yes - you must set up your Bot app as multitenant application. If no - your user test@test.com will be guest in your tenant and you should setup Teams access and Azure AD access allow to work with guests accounts. May be you must invite your user test@test.com as guest to your tenant. The error description directly says that the user does not exist in the tenant and you should add him as a guest. Did you try this?

Comment: @Maxim, thanks for your response.

I am building this bot for commercial use so any organization can installed this bot in their Teams workspace. It's not necessary that all organization will use the Azure AD. Right?
They can use office/work emails accounts. So, how we can get the token for that?

Comment: To setup connection into bot: add OAuth Connection String with next settings: 'AAD V2', ClientId=BotId (in AAD app registration), Client Secret =Bot Secret, Token Exchange URL= api://botid-<bot id guid>, Tenant ID empty or 'common', and in Scopes enumerate graph scopes. In bot app registration you grant access to graph, setup API permissions, setup Expose an API with Application ID URI api://botid-<botId>, add scopes, add client application if need and test it in Bot framework emulator. After your user test@test.com can access AD resources - you can configure MS Teams App as I mentioned early

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Maxim has also suggested, if you want to have a bot that should run multitenant you need to put tenant Id as `common` in OAuth Setting in Azure bot. As the value suggest it isn't going to specific to single tenant and Redirect Uri should be set to `https://token.botframework.com/.auth/web/redirect` in app registration.

This is it, you don't need to add anything.
This is also mention in the doc  --
[image]

We have some sample around it as well that shows how to use Graph API with the bot -

https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/main/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/24.bot-authentication-msgraph

You can setup this one and update the Graph calls to get member of team or channels.

Comment: Hey @hunaid-hanfee-msft, I was successfully able to authenticate from MS Teams now However I wanted to get the list of all the members in teams by using  'GET /teams/{team-id}/members'. Could you please let me know what is the value of '{team-id}' ? I tried looking at the 'TurnContext' that we receive when someone installs the bot and try to use all the ids mentioned there but none of them works and it says 'No Team found with Group id'.

Comment: I tried to use the tenant Id, id that I saw in context but none of them are working. FYI, I am using 'personal' scope.

Comment: FYI, I am able to retrieve all the groups using 'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/group'.

Comment: Quick Update:- so If I get the list of all the groups and then use that Id to call the 'GET /teams/{team-id}/members' then it works and gives me the members list. Is there a global team Id that gives me all members list or I have loop through the groups and get the list?

Comment: @DeveshTiwari - Method is available to get TeamInfo with turnContext - `turnContext.Activity.TeamsGetTeamInfo();` It returns [TeamInfo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.bot.schema.teams.teaminfo?view=botbuilder-dotnet-stable) of bot called from or installed in.

Here's link for [TeamsGetTeamInfo() Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.bot.schema.teams.teaminfo?view=botbuilder-dotnet-stable)